How can I increase the size of my /opt directory?
From following other posts, in order to increase the size of the /opt directory, one option is:
resize2fs -p /dev/mapper/rootvg-opt 

However when I run this I run into
resize2fs 1.47.0 (date) 
open: No such file or directory while opening /dev/mapper/rootvg-opt

I am trying to install Anaconda, and when I try to do it, I run into:
ERROR: Not enough free disk space: 247312 < 7208985



Do you have /opt on its own partition? Please edit your question and explain what actual problem you are trying to solve that makes you want to do this.

Thanks, just added more details at the end. How can I find the partition? Sorry quite new to this

Normally the /opt directory is not on its own partition, and resize2fs works on a whole partition. If you actually need to do this, you probably will have to resize the whole / partition. But that is not necessarily easy or safe depending on how your system is set up. If you give the command lsblk -e7  -o NAME,FSTYPE,LABEL,PARTLABEL,SIZE,FSUSED,MOUNTPOINT in a terminal, it will show useful information about your system and its partitions. The command does not do anything to your system, just prints info.

Thanks again for the help! I have added a screenshot with the details- does that help? I am not so familiar with 'NAME' but the first one seem slike it has a lot of space and none used** what does NAME represent?

NAME is the name of the partition or device (normally one or more partitions on a device). It's more helpful if you could copy the text and paste it instead of posting a screenshot in future, but this one seems readable enough for now. Unfortunately your partition layout is completely unfamiliar to me (no / directory) so hopefully someone familiar with this type of system will chime in.

ll the disk spaces seem tiny when I look at them - is this normal? I bought a chromebook recently and the OS system is incredible non-user friendly. Something as simple as installing Conda is an impossible task.. I've spent the entire day going through docs with no avail

Please don't post images of text. It makes it hard to read and impossible to search.

I just don't know much about Chromebooks. I have one, but I gave up and installed Debian linux on it.

it doesn't look like you use LVM at all
